# PHP String Concatenation Issue

Tags: php, html, css, templates

I am learning PHP by myself and I wonder if you guys can help me to solve my problem. I want to concatenate 2 variables that are align right in the form of an hyperlink with a word. I can do that no problem, but the word is not getting aligned right as well. I have tried somethings, but it doesnt work. Please see my code:

```
<?php
     $log = ( '<a style="float:right; "href="login.php">login </a>'  ) ;
     $reg = ( '<a style="float:right; "href="login.php">register </a>' );
     echo $log ." or " .  $reg;
?>
```

I need login or register to be displayed on the top right of the page, but I dont want to hyperlink the word "or".
Also, if you guys have any links for good tutorials on PHP or tutorials on how to create a good website design, maybe templates, please paste here. I am starting with websites now and I am learning by myself. Any help is appreciatted.   :-)

Comment: This does not seem like a PHP issue, sounds more like you need to tweak your CSS to me

Comment: Any reason you aren't using plain HTML for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are thinking wrong in terms of HTML/CSS markup. HTML code that will be generated by your script looks as follows:

```
<a style="float:right; "href="login.php">login </a> or <a style="float:right; "href="login.php">register </a>
```

It will first float "login" to the right, then append "register" to the left of "login".
I would suggest doing it this way:

```
<?php
    $log = '<a href="login.php">login </a>';
    $reg = '<a href="login.php">register </a>';
    echo sprintf("<div style='float:right;'>%s or %s</div>", $log, $reg);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap them in a container div thats floated right,
float the links left and make the or a span that is floated left as well.

```
<?php
 $log = ( '<a style="float:left; "href="login.php">login </a>'  ) ;
 $reg = ( '<a style="float:left; "href="login.php">register </a>' );
 echo '<div style="float:right;">'.$log .'<span style="float:left;"> or </span>'.$reg.'</div>';
```

also, its better to assign classes.  you could write all that markup just by assigning a class to the container div

Comment: `style="float:left; "href="login.php"` is incorrect, you need a space before `href`.

Comment: ah, I just copy and pasted his code as its not really pertinent to his actual question.

Comment: I assumed it was relevant, because of `but I dont want to hyperlink the word "or"`... but I fear I may be incorrect. Testing in Firefox proved to be forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating both of your anchor tags in a div tag that is floated to the right.

```
<?php
     $log = '<a href="login.php">login</a>' ;
     $reg = '<a href="login.php">register</a>';
     echo "<div style='float:right; width:200px;'>$log or $reg</div>";
?>
```

also, notice how inside of double quotes, you can put a variable as i've done in my echo statement.

Comment: Oh i never noticed the  incorrect double quotes on the href's. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score -1):

If you need a CMS try some existing distributions instead of inventing the wheel again.

For templates use something like [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net).